# React Native: shouldComponentUpdate() not preventing render() from being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lifecycle

I have a React Native component where I want to prevent the render() method from being called.

```
class A extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  render() {
    return(...)
  }
}
```

Returning `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate` should prevent `render()` from being called, but it doesn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't stop the first render if that's what you are asking, or else you need to give some more details about your code.

Comment: It doesn't prevent re-rendering either unfortunately. Are there other parts of my code that I could share that would help?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it prevents a *rerender* but not the initial rendering. This is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

and

> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

Hence, if you return false, then you only prevent a rerendering on state changes.

Comment: It doesn't prevent re-rendering either unfortunately. Are there other parts of my code that I could share that would help?

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be necessary to see the code which triggers the state changes which causes a rerendering of your component.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use hooks useMemo or useCallback https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html
to choose what you want to update